# How do I get per-cpu stats (system, idle, nice, ...) like the "top" command does?

Tags: c, linux, cpu-usage

On linux, I'd like to know what "C" API to call to get the per-cpu stats.

I know about and could read `/proc/loadavg` from within my app, but this is the system-wide load avarages, not the per-cpu information.  I want to tell the individual CPUs or cores apart.

As an example of an application that does this, When I run `top` and press "1", I can see the 4 or 8 processors/cores like this:

```
Cpu0  :  4.5%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  : 42.2%us,  6.2%sy,  0.5%ni, 51.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  :  3.0%us,  1.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 94.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  :  7.0%us,  4.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 88.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
```

I've tried to `strace top` but this led to a rat's nest.

Comment: This interesting question should have been migrated to [Unix&Linux.SE.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/?as=1)

Comment: @Vorac uh, no? It's asking about C API. Not shell or the kernel device files (although `/proc` will probably be used anyways).

Comment: @rubenvb, you have good point. On the other hand. reading a file in /proc applies equally to users, admins and programmers. And the question is linux-specific. But then, there is `linux` tag here. On the other hand, this site is quite overloaded and it would be nice to spread some of the topics to it's sister SE-es. Oh, I got so mixed up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file you want is `/proc/stat`.  (You might want to refer to `fs/proc/stat.c` in the Linux kernel source.)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a real answer but I would take a look at the source code of top.

Comment: The source code for top can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/unixtop/

Answer (score 0):

I guess kernel file timer.c may be of some importance in this scenario to calculate load averages. From the file timer.c function calc_load()

```
unsigned long avenrun[3];

static inline void calc_load(unsigned long ticks) 
{

    unsigned long active_tasks; /* fixed-point */
    static int count = LOAD_FREQ;

    count -= ticks;
    if (count < 0) {
        count += LOAD_FREQ;
        active_tasks = count_active_tasks();
        CALC_LOAD(avenrun[0], EXP_1, active_tasks);
        CALC_LOAD(avenrun[1], EXP_5, active_tasks);
        CALC_LOAD(avenrun[2], EXP_15, active_tasks);
    }
}
```